# CPT while loop not working

Tags: loop, array

I am having problems getting anything out of this while loop:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'Smart panels',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'post_views_count'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($query_args);
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

        echo "<li>post</li>";

    endwhile; 
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE :-). Side note: Please properly indent your code when adding it to the editor. Make your code as easy readable as possible for others. Proper details and properly added code usually attract good answers qiuckly

Comment: That CAN'T be the name of your post type.

Comment: If you havent done so, please also read [ask], [help] and visit our [tour] page

Answer (score 1):

Your post type is all wrong. Custom post type names **cannot** contain spaces or camelcase, also names should not contain special characters. Custom post type names, and for that matter, custom taxonomy names **should** be all lowercase letters, and names must **only** be separated by underscores (`_`)

Have a look at the `$post_type` parameter in [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

> **$post_type**
>
> (string) (required) Post type. (max. 20 characters, can not contain capital letters or spaces)
>
> Default: None